# CakePHP 3 - Time::now() returns wrong value

Tags: cakephp, time

Today's date is **2016-12-27**.

```
$now = Time::now();
echo $now; //returns wrong value (year) 2017-12-27 15:24:47
echo $now->format('Y-m-d'); //returns corect value 2016-12-27
```

This is crazy. Why 'echo Time::now();' returns the wrong year value?

Comment: I haven't used version 3 yet but you can probably find out that data type `Time::now()` returns and (since it appears to be an object) what its `__toString()` method looks like.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that's the problem with echo.

```
$now should be in object format i guess,that's why echo can't give you proper value.
```

Try using:

```
debug($now); // or print_r($now);
```

And after using format method, the result is converted to string and echo giving you right value.